# Splitting a list into all combinations

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am aware of many posts with the similar questions and have been through many of them. However, I am not able to do what I need.

I have list L=[0,1,2,3,4,5] which I want to split into a pair of tuples. For example:

```
[(0,1,2),(3,4,5)]
[(0,1,3),(2,4,5)]
[(0,1,4),(2,4,5)]
...
```

Each tuple needs to contain half of the elements from the original list (in this example 3 of 6). A solution needs to produce every combination of tuples using 3 elements.

I can easily find all the possible tuple within the list using

```
list(itertools.combinations(L, 3))
```

`[(0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 3),
 (0, 1, 4),
 (0, 1, 5),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (0, 2, 4),
 ...]`

Does `itertools` offers any workround for this as well?

Comment: It kind of depends on whether all list items are unique and how you want to deal with duplicates. You could try using `set`s or creating all possible permutations of the original list and splitting each permutation in half.

Comment: Do/Will you have any duplicate value in that list?

Comment: At the moment there are not duplicates but a general solution would be great

Comment: Without duplicates given answer or mine will work but with duplicates.. well. You'll need a different approach.

Comment: `L = set([0,1,2,3,4,5]); print([[x, tuple(L.difference(x))] for x in itertools.combinations(L, 3)])` maybe converting to set at start would save a lot on set conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be more performant solutions that avoid a complete extra iteration of the list for the other half, but that should be rather negligible:

```
l = [[x, tuple(y for y in L if y not in x)] for x in combinations(L, 3)]
[[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5)],
 [(0, 1, 3), (2, 4, 5)],
 [(0, 1, 4), (2, 3, 5)],
 [(0, 1, 5), (2, 3, 4)],
 [(0, 2, 3), (1, 4, 5)],
 [(0, 2, 4), (1, 3, 5)],
 [(0, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4)],
 [(0, 3, 4), (1, 2, 5)],
 [(0, 3, 5), (1, 2, 4)],
 [(0, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3)],
 [(1, 2, 3), (0, 4, 5)],
 [(1, 2, 4), (0, 3, 5)],
 [(1, 2, 5), (0, 3, 4)],
 [(1, 3, 4), (0, 2, 5)],
 [(1, 3, 5), (0, 2, 4)],
 [(1, 4, 5), (0, 2, 3)],
 [(2, 3, 4), (0, 1, 5)],
 [(2, 3, 5), (0, 1, 4)],
 [(2, 4, 5), (0, 1, 3)],
 [(3, 4, 5), (0, 1, 2)]]
```

This depends on the absence of duplicates in the original list. Otherwise you'd have to work with the indexes instead. The following modification uses the same approach, but uses the list indexes for the combinations and can thus handle duplicates in the original list:

```
indexes = ((x, (y for y in L if y not in x)) for x in combinations(range(len(L)), 3))
l = [[tuple(L[a] for a in A), tuple(L[b] for b in B)] for A, B in indexes]
```

Comment: you could replace everything inside `tuple` with `set(L) - set(x)`

Comment: That would jeopardize the order, however, and I am fairly sure there is some serious overhead to the set conversions.